# How to determine the net velocity change applied by a force vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, velocity, vectors

I am a little stumped by the answer of this question.

The question reads,

"In three situations, a single force acts on a moving particle. Here are the velocities (at that instant) and the forces:

$(1)$ $\bf{v}$ = $-4i$ m/s, $\bf{F}$ $= (6i-20j)$N;

$(2)$ $\bf{v}$ = $2i-3j$ m/s, $\bf{F}$ $= (-2j+7k)$N;

$(3)$ $\bf{v}$ = $-3i+j$ m/s, $\bf{F}$ $= (2i+6j)$N;

Rank the situations according to the rate at which energy is being transferred, greatest transfer to the particle ranked first, greatest transfer from the particle ranked last."

According to the answers, the energy transfer can be ranked as follows,

$2, 3, 1$

In my attempt to answer the problem I took the magnitudes of each of the associated forces. (Assuming that a greater net force would have the greatest influence on the particle's velocity)

So by my logic,

$|F_{(1)}| = 20.9N$

$|F_{(2)}| = 7.28N$  $\implies$ The ranking should read, $1, 2,$ and $3$

$|F_{(3)}| = 3.32N$

Could anyone point me in the right direction and explain where I am going wrong? Does it have something to do with the components?

i.e. The force, $\bf{F}$ $= (ai+bj)$N, at a particular instant can only affect the velocity, $\bf{v}$ = $(ci+dk)$ m/s, in  in the $i$ direction because they both share one vector component in the same direction?

Or have I gone completely off the rails and this actually so much simpler than I'm making it out to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joules per seconds is Power.

Power is work done per unit time. (J/s)

Work is Force x Distance x Cos(angle)

Dividing by time to get power yields 
Force x Distance / Time x Cos(angle)

Velocity is Distance / Time and therefore Power = Force x Velocity x Cos(angle)

Since the direction of the application of the force doesn't matter in this problem you can derive the answer from **Power = Force x Velocity **

Comment: So in my case above, I take the dot product of the vector sets?

Comment: Force and velocity are both vectors so taking the dot product would make the most sense; however it may be a multiplication of the magnitudes. Whichever yields the correct answer must be correct

Answer (score 0):

The initial answer is exactly right, and your response shows you understand that the dot product of the force and velocity will give you a scaler value that leads to the right answer.

However when I read the question, I was impressed at how hard it is to visualize what is really going on, and the incurable teacher in me thought you might be interested in a physical feel for what is going on.  The following is just a discussion of why just looking at the force doesn't give the right results. If you don't have the time to ponder this just stick with the answer above and skip the rest, it is just enrichment.

There is always a certain amount of confusion between work and power.  This confusion is aggravated by the various units that different disciplines use for Energy and power.  In physics the unit of energy is joules and power is joules per second.  In the electrical world power is watts and work/energy is watt-hours.
The tricky port of this problem is that it is asking for " rate at which energy is being transferred"  which is power; and power (i.e.the rate of energy being transferred is going to be changing constantly as the force changes the particles velocity.  As stated work is force x distance, but in this case the distance over which the force is being applied is a variable changing because of the force changing the velocity. 
Consider a simple one dimensional example, a 1 kg particle in standard gravity starting at 0 m/s will have a force of 9.8 N on it so after it falls 1 meter it will have had picked up a total of 9.8 joules, but since its velocity is constantly changing, the TIME that it takes to travel the first cm is a lot longer than the TIME it takes to travel the last cm, so the power (i.e. the instantaneous force times distance divided by the instantaneous time is will be much higher at the 100 cm mark than at the initial 0 cm mark because the divisor (TIME) will be much smaller.

Another way of thinking of this is that when you drop the particle, it will gain 9.8 joules of energy for every meter it falls, but since its velocity is constantly increasing the time it will take to gain that 9.8 joules will be getting shorter and shorter, so the rate of change of energy will be getting more and more.

On the other hand if you propelled a 1 kg particle up at an initial velocity of 39.2 m/s (4 * 9.8) then initially it would be loosing kinetic energy much faster that at the peak of its travel.

Once you have a good handle on what is really going on, then knowing that the vector dot product of the force and velocity gives you power makes answering test questions much easier.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation Bill. So you're essentially saying that I should treat gravity in your example as the force in my question?

Comment: Well sort of.  I was just trying to help you visualize what is supposedly happening.  The forces in the problem are difficult for me to visualize, unless you try to graph the thing out.  The first force is pushing strongly down and to the right.  The particle initially is moving to the left.  At time = 0 the particle starts slowing down in the i or x direction and starts picking up velocity in the -j or y direction.  Thus initially the particle is transferring energy to the force, since it has no velocity in any direction except the i or x direction.  Can you visualize that?  Its hard for me.

Comment: At time t =0+ the particle starts to gain velocity in the negative j or y direction, so it starts the force is starting to transfer energy to the particle in that direction while still slowing it down in the i of x direction.  Since all this is so hard for me to visualize, I like to simplify things to 1 dimension when possible so thinking about a particle moving up and down in a regular gravitational field makes it easier.  The reason that this is a good problem is because we usually don't think much about power in classical mechanics like this;

Comment: in classical mechanics we usually think in terms of work or energy which are different words for the same property and measured in joules.  The units of power is watts (Joules/sec) but is seldom thought about in these sort of problems, which is why this one is a good one, it stretches your understanding of what all is going on.  Since work in one dimension is Force times Distance,  a particle falling straight down in a G field is constantly gaining energy at an ever increasing rate, so the power from the G field is increasing as the speed increases because it traversing distance faster.

Comment: Hope this helps.  Once you have a handle on this then its good to remember that Power is the dot product of the instantaneous velocity vector and the force vector.